# Make authentified GET request to twitter API

Tags: c++, oauth, twitter

I managed to get token/token secret for making identified request to twitter API. Nethertheless i do not manage to do such request in C++ using QOAuth

I am trying to access "http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json"

I use this code

```
_oauthInterface = new QOAuth::Interface(this);
_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

_oauthInterface->setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
_oauthInterface->setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY);

QOAuth::ParamMap params;
    params.insert("user_id", QString::number(id).toAscii());
    params.insert("cursor", cursor.toAscii());

QString url("http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json");

QByteArray header = _oauthInterface->createParametersString(url,
                                                            QOAuth::GET,
                                                            token.toUtf8(),
                                                            tokenSecret.toUtf8(),
                                                            QOAuth::HMAC_SHA1,
                                                            params,
                                                            QOAuth::ParseForHeaderArguments);

QNetworkRequest request;
if(!params.isEmpty())
    url.append(_oauthInterface->inlineParameters(params, QOAuth::ParseForInlineQuery));

request.setUrl(url);
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", header);

_manager->get(request);

QObject::connect(_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyHandler(QNetworkReply*)));
```

after 150 request I get

```
"{"error":"Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.","request":"\/1\/followers\/ids.json?cursor=-1&user_id=xxxxxxxxx"}"
```

as an answer. How come I am not identified ?

Answer (score 0):

how silly I am. This code is good, I just called this function with the wrong arguments (token / token) instead of (token / token secret)

Notice that Twitter doesn't inform you if access token are invalid